# Ubuntu 12.04 Mysql Won't Install

Tags: installation, mysql

Error when i trying to install mysql-server on Ubuntu 12.04

AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: abstractions/mysql
start: Job failed to start

Comment: This is just not enough. Please give at least step-by-step instructions to reproduce this. Also, the logs from syslog would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wont share the time and failures on repairing a mysql install on 12.04 but here is what I did having most if not all the symptoms of multiple faulures.

```
  sudo apt-get --purge apparmor
```

(reinstall after done?)

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-* mysql-server-* mysql-core-* mysql-workbench-*
```

(the * is all files related to that tag

```
 sudo aptitude purge ~c
```

(must have aptitude installed)
check removal of all files by:

```
 sudo dpkg --get-selections
```

(you can replace with `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql`) but i reccomend the first because a clean file structure runs well. 
Then reinstall using:

```
 sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server-5.5
```

and whatever else mysql packages you need. 
I have reproduced the error most of us have been getting and this fixed it each time.

**NOTE!!! DO NOT STOP PASSWORD SETUP WHEN CONFIGURING MYSQL_SERVER_5.5!!!**